# Using large text files in different languages in Android

Tags: android, multilingual

In the app I'm building, I'm using multiple languages. It's easy to add a different language into an app by adding a new folder (for example: values-fr) and adding a new strings.xml file in there. But I have pretty large text files (complete articles) that I need to add. These articles are also written in different languages. What is the best way to add them to my app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd consider using `res/raw-<qualifiers>` as alternative to the assets. The `raw` folder can store arbitrary files in their - you guessed it - raw form. For example, a 'Hello World' article written in French and English, would be stored under:

- `res/raw-fr`
- `res/raw-en`

The raw resource can then be opened by calling [`openRawResource(int id)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#openRawResource%28int%29) on a resources object, similar to how it works for other resources like drawables, strings etc. The id's generated by the framework will be in the familiar format of `R.raw.filename` (without file extension).

The benefit of using this approach is that you can fully leverage Android's localization system, meaning that as a developer you basically don't have to worry about any of that at all. You can also easily add more qualifiers to further filter on device characteristics (e.g. screen size, density, platform version etc etc - [see here for a full overview](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#table2)). The downside is that it imposes some limitations in terms of the original file name/extension and doesn't support a proper folder/file hierarchy.

The 'better' approach (/raw vs /assets that is) will probably depend on your project's requirements.

Comment: Great answer, thanks. Just tested it and it works like a charm

Answer (score 3):

I would probably use assets -- that is, create *assets/data/fr/* and store the *fr* files there. Note that assets require explicit extraction -- which probably is good since you may save memory having only one set of articles installed.

Another possibility is to place everything on an http server, and thus make both keeping and accessing the articles somebody else's problem :) .

BTW, if you files are really big, you will have to install the application without them, and download the articles later. (There are restrictions on the apk size.)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I'm actually writing my thesis on optimizing Android and I want to make it available in an app aswell but I haven't made any multi language apps yet. Because there won't be any changes to it, I won't use a http server. I'll try using assets and if I don't get a better answer, I'll accept this one. Thanks!

Comment: using the raw resources, seems to work better for me since I don't have to care about localization anymore.