# Android: multiple translations for multiple screen sizes

Tags: android

I have a German app and now I have to make it multilingual.

I have a button with little space but a long word. So far with only one language I have worked for the different screen sizes small, large and xlarge with different short forms

```
values-xlarge/strings: "Standortinformationen"
values-large/strings:  "Standortinfos"
values-small/strings:  "Stdortinfo"
```

Therefore I have the question, if a string can be translated not only for different languages but also for different display sizes

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using large text files in different languages in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15943540/using-large-text-files-in-different-languages-in-android)

Comment: Thank You. There was a good link, wich helped me a lot. I will soon write an anwser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Qualifier name rules](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#QualifierRules) are the Solution.
So I could create the following folders

```
res/values
res/values-de
res/values-de-small
res/values-de-large
res/values-de-xlarge
```

Each of these folders gets a "strings.xml" file with the specific translations